# (simple) AHK: RegexMatch "\n[^\n]$" doesn't work

Tags: regex, autohotkey

What am I doing wrong here?

```
Shells := "`nAlpha`nBetta`nOmega"
RegexMatch(Shells, "\n[^\n]$", LastLetter)
MsgBox % "The last letter is: " . LastLetter
```

The last letter should be Omega, but it doesn't happen so in my case.

EDIT:

1) "`n" is a single LineFeed character.

2) LastLetter is (the name of) a variable that must contain string "`nOmega".

Comment: What happens in your case? What should happen? Please elaborate in the question.

Comment: Try `"\`n.+$"`.

Comment: Just a note on quantifiers: `*` will match *0 or more* occurrences, and `+` will match *1 or more* occurrences. Choose the one that suits best (`*` is good if you also want to get just a `newline` if there is nothing after it, and `+` if you do not want to get any match at all if there is nothing after a newline).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a quantifier in addition to `\z` token (I'm not sure how multi-line mode is handled in AutoHotKey regex engine but you can leave `$` intact if multi-line mode is off by default):

```
RegexMatch(Shells, "\n[^\n]*\z", LastLetter)
```